# Track pad not support in Honor magicbook X16

Tags: touchpad, ubuntu-drivers, gestures

After installing 22.04 on my Honor Magicbook X16, the trackpad is not detected. I have attempted to use it by following all the instructions, but to no avail. and also gestures is not supported

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ BLTP7853:00 347D:7853 Touchpad            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ BLTP7853:00 347D:7853 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ BLTP7853:00 347D:7853 UNKNOWN             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Huawei WMI hotkeys                        id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
lampros@lampros-BRN-FXXC:~$
```

Comment: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/my-touchpad-was-recognized-as-a-mouse/145157

it was works but when i restart the PC it shouled not working for that i have to enable everytime by using

sudo hid-feature set -f 30000 3 /dev/hidraw0